# how print specific key or value in foreach loop

Tags: wordpress, loops, foreach

hi i have this code i used `print_r` to print array keys and values but i have a problem this my code contain five arrays and every array contain one key[0] i want print the specific key only for example i want the keys only contain the videos

how can only `iframe` values?

this is my foreach loop

```
$video_meta = get_post_meta($post->ID);

    foreach ($video_meta as $video_metas) {
        print_r($video_metas);
    }
```

this is my result of above code

Array
(
    [0] => 1396282271:1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
)
Array
(
    [0] => 13
)
Array
(
    [0] => 'iframe')
Array
(
    [0] => 'iframe')

Comment: Can you post the complete array (variable `video_meta`)? Try to use the `single` variable: `get_post_meta($post->ID, null, true);`

Comment: this is my complete array Array ( [0] => 1396282271:1 ) Array ( [0] => 1 ) Array ( [0] => 13 ) Array ( [0] => 'iframe') Array ( [0] => 'iframe') all arrays have the 0 key  but i want print the 0 keys contain the iframe or videos

Comment: i used this code get_post_meta($post->ID, null, true); but still i cant print the videos only

Comment: Its not the complete array, you print each row and not the complete array. If you need only specific meta data than set it on post meta: `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'video');`

Comment: i tried to use that code but still don't work with me

Comment: Sorry, i mean `iframe` and not `video`. You need to get only the data of the `iframe` meta